# How can I travel to Russia for the 2018 FIFA World Cup without flying?

Tags: europe, transportation, russia, sports-events

On the occasion of the World Cup of Nations in Russia, many people will be interested in traveling there. The problem is the expense for airline and match ticket. For me, who's passionate about football, I'd like to be able to go to Russia to follow the event more closely,

What transport ways, other than airlines, can I take to get to Russia from Paris, for example?

Comment: Welcome! You're still relatively new, so I'll remind you that asking non-specific questions with multiple possible answers is considered off topic. Please have a read of the [help], and edit your question to a specific problem you face.  There are literally hundreds of possible ways to get to Russia from Europe (where are you in Europe?), and you'll need to be more specific in your request. Thanks

Comment: Russia is a big place. Europe is a big place. Cheapest, most comfortable, and fastest are all different criteria and somewhat mutually exclusive. Could you clarify what you're looking for exactly?

Comment: Plus, you might want to specify which city you're especially interested in. Answers will vary greatly depending on whether you're headed for Kaliningrad, St. Petersburg, Sochi or Yekaterinburg (or one of the other 7 cities).

Comment: @Sabine I'm actuelly  interested in 3 cites in russia, but I think it will be easy for me to move inside russia by the [FAN ID](https://www.fan-id.ru/)

Comment: @HankyPanky I would like to move to russia to support my team with the budget as little as possible

Comment: @hisi Note that "move to Russia" suggests "become a resident of Russia"; you probably mean "travel to Russia".

Comment: prices around big sporting events will always be high, no real way around that

Comment: You can ride a train from Paris! http://pass.rzd.ru/static/public/en?STRUCTURE_ID=5125&layer_id=3290&refererLayerId=162&id=2039

Comment: This is still too broad. Yes, there trains, but they are still expensive. If you have time to travel, you can reach the closest city by train or cruise ship, after that use local trains via Fan Id (there will be fast trains for team supporters)

Comment: @alamar that would be more expensive than flying and *much* more inconvenient. Possibly the only country where traveling to Moscow by train makes sense is Finland.

Comment: @JonathanReez for Poland that's a possibility too, maybe for Germany (Berlin) and possibly Czech. BTW, did you check actual prices? I guess there are days when train will be cheaper, especially with the imminent. World Cup.

Comment: @alamar nope, I guarantee a flight would always be cheaper and much faster. Especially since not all of the World Cup matches are held in Moscow.

Comment: @JonathanReez I believe that with FanID he can get free internal rail. See the link s/he posted in a comment. Speed is another issue of course as you suggest.

Comment: @JonathanReez right now, for this Saturday, the cheapest flight from Warzaw to Moscow is $240 but coupe (nice sleeper) in train is $150.

Comment: @alamar thé World Cup Is in the summer, not this Saturday. And the train is painfully slow.

Comment: It's not that this question is too broad, it is that it is asking for an itinerary, which is _specifically_ off topic. How is this different that asking "please make my travel plans for me." WANTA

Answer (score 7):

There are several possibilities:

- You can travel from Paris (or Nice, or some other countries) to Moscow by train - [Official Russian Railway site](http://pass.rzd.ru/static/public/en?STRUCTURE_ID=5125&layer_id=3290&refererLayerId=3290&id=2039). It will take you less than 40 hours and I doubt that it would be cheaper than flying. And you might need to have a visa for Belarus. There are also trains from Helsinki to Saint-Petersburg.
- You can travel to Saint-Petersburg by bus from some German or Polish cities ([link](http://www.fernbus24.de/bus-berlin-saintpetersburg/)).
- There are ferries from Baltic countries, Sweden and Finnland to Saint-Petersrburg.

Comment: There are also buses from Tallinn, and train from Helsinki

Answer (score 4):

The World Cup is held in [12 different cities](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_FIFA_World_Cup#Venues) which are very much far from each other, so the answer depends on which games you are planning to visit:

1. Kaliningrad is the easiest - you can take the train (or fly on a low-cost airline) to Gdansk and take a bus from there to Russia. This would be cheaper than flying through Moscow and not too inconvenient.
2. St. Petersburg *might* be viable if you fly to Estonia or Finland first and then take a bus/train to Russia. From Helsinki the train costs ~30 EUR and takes 4 hours. From Tallinn there's an 8 hour bus for 20 EUR.
3. If you do visit St. Petersburg first, it would also be viable to take the train to Moscow from there. For 50-100 EUR there's an express train between the two cities, taking 4 hours.
4. In every other case you are *much* better off flying as it would be cheaper and *a lot faster*. Unless flight tickets  prices increase astronomically there's no way you would save money by traveling over land.

Apparently Russia promised to provide some form of free public [transport for fans](https://www.fan-id.ru/help.html), however the details are currently too vague to provide a proper answer. If you're willing to wait, hold out for an official announcement on how the system would work.

Comment: AFAIK, the plans are to provide some free trains for Fan ID holders